# Remote Debugging disconnects very frequently for Intellij

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea, remote-debugging

I am trying to remote debug my code using intellij but it disconnects in a few seconds . Can anyone suggest how can I prevent or increase the time of disconnection.

Comment: That's not many details to go by.  What type of application?  Running on what type of server?  What is the error specifically?  For java/tomcat, you'll need to ensure the selected jdw port is open and configured correctly on the remote machine.  Then in the startup/connection tab of the run/debug configuration, select "debug" and enter the port there.

Comment: I am running the Spring boot maven application  .I am try  to debug one of the services which is deployed on k8s by using the port /configuration details.

Answer (score 12):

I suspect it is likely not a problem exactly with the Intellij remote debugger.  It is likely the fact you are spending time with the JVM completely stopped.

For my situation (with exactly the same symptoms), I was always disconnected after about 1 minute of stepping through the code and looking at things.  It was Kubernetes restarting the pod due to liveness check failures.  When the pod is restarted the debugger is disconnected.

I solved my problem by changing the breakpoint to be "suspend the thread" rather than "suspend the jvm".

Comment: this solved my problem as well